# Unable to launch Minecraft Java Edition, error code 0x803F8001

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

First time getting Minecraft Java, if I try to open the launcher, it gives me this error:

> Minecraft Launcher is currently not available in your account. Make sure you are signed in to the Store and try again. Here’s the error code, in case you need it: 0x803F8001

I'm pretty sure I'm signed into the store already, but it keeps giving me this error when I try to open the installer or launcher.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

I have a list of things you could do to possible solve this issue.

1. **Check & Install Windows Updates:**

- Use this shortcut Windows key + <kbd>I</kbd> to open the Settings.
- After that, you have to choose Update & Security.
- It will open the Windows Update settings by default.
- Now, you have to click the Check for updates button.
- Then, install the updates and restart your system.

2. **Run Automatic Repair:**

- Use this shortcut Windows key + <kbd>I</kbd> to open the Settings.
- Then, you have to click on Update & Security.
- In the left pane, you have to click on Recovery.
- Now, you have to click on the Restart now button under Advanced
  startup.
- After that, you have to select Advanced Options → Troubleshoot.
- At last, you have to choose Automatic Repair and wait for the
  computer to reboot automatically.

3. **Re-register the Windows Store App**:

- Go to the Start menu, search for 'powershell' in the search box.
- Right-click on the top result and choose Run as administrator.
- Now, copy and paste the below command and hit Enter.

```
Get-appxprovisionedpackage –online | where-object {$_.packagename –like “*windowscommunicationsapps*”} | remove-appxprovisionedpackage –online
```

- Reboot your PC once the process gets completed.

4. **Reset the Windows Store Cache:**

- You have to press the Windows key and R together to open the Run
  command.
- Then, you have to type the below command and click the OK button.

  `wsreset.exe`
- It will open the Microsoft Store along with a Command Prompt and
  resets the Windows Store cache.
- After this, you have to reboot your PC to apply the changes.

5. **Run the DISM Command:**

- Click the Start menu and type 'cmd' in the search box. Then press
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Command Prompt with admin privileges.
- In the Command Prompt, you have to type the below command and hit
  Enter

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

- Run the below command and hit Enter if your Windows Update client is
  damaged or corrupted.

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\RepairSource\Windows /LimitAccess
```

6. **Disable the Proxy Server:**

- Using the shortcut Windows key + <kbd>R</kbd>, you can open the Run box.
- After that, you have to type 'inetcpl.cpl' in the given space of Open
  and click OK.
- It will open the Internet Properties and you have to click the
  Connections tab.
- Click the LAN settings button.
- Select the check-box of 'Automatically detect setting' and uncheck
  the ‘Use a Proxy Server for your LAN’ option and click the OK button.
- Then, click the Apply and OK button in the Internet Properties
  window. At last, reboot your device.

7. **Turn on Location Service:**

- To open the Settings, you have to use this keyboard shortcut Windows
  key + <kbd>I</kbd>.
- After that, you have to choose the Privacy option.
- In the left pane, you have to click on the Location option under App
  permission
- Now, on the right side, you have to turn on the toggle switch under
  'Allow apps to access your location'.
- Reboot your PC to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help but I also had this problem and spent like two hours trying to fix it. Anyway, the thing that fixed my issue was simply travelling to the Microsoft Store and clicking the "get" button next to the play "button." I think the problem I was having was that I had gotten Minecraft before merging my Java and Microsoft accounts. Because of this Microsoft never registered that I had bought Minecraft. The simple click made me feel stupid, but I can play Minecraft now.